# Trying to store a URL as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm trying to store some details about a number of sites using HTML5 local storage, and I've run into a bit of a wall.

Basically, I want the application to be able to cache data offline, and the way I've been developing it, every time the main page loads, the content is cached as localStorage.sitedata. I'm storing it as JSON.

The code I've written for it looks like this:

```
            // Retrieve response as JSON
            response = $.parseJSON(data);

            // Store the data in HTML5 local storage as well
            var dataToCacheArray = new Array();
            for(var item in response){
                var obj = response[item];
                dataToCacheArray.push(obj);
            }
            var dataToCache = JSON.stringify(dataToCacheArray);
            localStorage.sitedata = dataToCache;
```

Now, the data in dataToCacheArray is exactly what I want - it's an array containing a number of JavaScript objects. Here's one of them, as shown in Chrome's developer tools if I use console.log() to view dataToCacheArray:

```
lastChecked: "13:46:55 Wednesday 15 August 2012"
siteId: "34"
status: "1"
success: "1"
url: "http://localhost"
```

Afterwards, I store a stringified version of dataToCacheArray as dataToCache, and if I view that with console.log(), I get this:

```
[{"status":"1","success":"1","siteId":"34","lastChecked":"13:46:55 Wednesday 15 August 2012"}]
```

As you can see, for some reason the URL is not included in the stringified version. Any idea as to where I might have gone awry?

Comment: which JSON library are you using?

Comment: @PhonicUK None - I'm developing it in Chrome, which I understand supports JSON.stringify() natively

Comment: If you rename the field to something other than "url" (or put in any non-url content) does it then work?

Comment: just out of curiosity-- why can't you just do this...            response = $.parseJSON(data);
It seems to me that the loop is just getting the values from the object-- you would basically be losing the "keys".

            var dataToCache = JSON.stringify(response);
            localStorage.sitedata = dataToCache;

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zSbRe/1

Comment: @PhonicUK If I rename obj.url to "bananas", it does include "bananas" as the URL, so maybe JSON.stringify() doesn't like URLs.

Comment: Try setting url to encodeURIComponent(url)

Comment: @PhonicUK Yes, that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the URL to encodeURIComponent(url) so that it is properly escaped in the original data before serializing to JSON.